# Send and receive UDP packets to server on different network android

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have looked all over for a solution to this problem, I have not come up with a solution that works.

Currently, I send and receive packets on my android device emulator using my loopback/localHost address. This proccess works successfuly, however when I try running the same code using my computer's public address the server never receives the packets.

```
private String hostName = "99.248.222.229";
//private String hostName = "10.0.2.2";
private InetAddress hostAddress;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    CreateAddress addressGetter = new CreateAddress();
    try {
        hostAddress = addressGetter.execute(hostName).get();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Button btnLock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLock);
    btnLock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendReceiveTask = new runUdpClient();
            byte[] udpMsg = {(byte)housenumber, (byte)doornumber, LK_MSG, UNLOCK};
            System.out.println(hostAddress);
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg, udpMsg.length, hostAddress, portnumber);
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = null;
            try {
                receivePacket = sendReceiveTask.execute(sendPacket).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            currentDoorState = (receivePacket.getData()[3]==UNLOCK);
            updateDoorStatus(currentDoorState);
            int doorNum = doornumber;
            eventArrayList.add(0, (getCurrentTimeStamp() + eventString.replace("doornum", Integer.toString(doorNum)))+ ((currentDoorState) ? "unlocked." : "locked."));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}

private  class runUdpClient extends AsyncTask<DatagramPacket, Void, DatagramPacket>{

    @Override
    protected DatagramPacket doInBackground(DatagramPacket ...params){

        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        //SEND
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            DatagramPacket dp;
            //dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), hostAddress, portnumber);
            dp = params[0];
            ds.send(dp);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //RECEIVE
        DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[100], 100);
        try {
            ds.setSoTimeout(1000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ds.receive(incomingPacket);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(ds != null) ds.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Packet recieved from server" + Arrays.toString(incomingPacket.getData()));
        return incomingPacket;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you use your computer address are you using the emulator or your phone ? if you are using your phone device you need to be connected to the same network as your computer  (both the pc and the phone device must be connected to the same network).
and try to create a rule in the firewall for the port number used by the application

Comment: @alihassoun what if I want to send packets across networks, that is what I am trying to do, is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by computer public address? Is it an address in your LAN behind the router? Are you testing with the emulator?

Comment: if you need to do it across networks you shall use a public IP  for the server (REAL FIX IP )